# Unable to search using JSON_CONTAINS

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-json

I am using the following query to search for a json value named "JavaScript"

When I run the query I get 0 results

This is my insert command I am using

```
INSERT INTO admin_acc_mngmt_notes (tags) VALUES('["JavaScript"]')
```

This is the search query I am using:

```
SELECT * FROM admin_acc_mngmt_notes WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags,'["JavaScript"]');
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I tested with MySQL 8.0.1 and it works perfectly. What version are you using? When you get 0 results, do you get any error?

Comment: Hi Bill. I found out the answer

SELECT * FROM `admin_acc_mngmt_notes`  WHERE JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'all', 'JavaScript') IS NOT NULL

Comment: Very well. You should post that as a solution, and accept it, so this question doesn't get treated as an "unanswered" question forever.

Comment: Thanks i did it!

Answer (score 3):

I found out the answer myself:

```
SELECT * FROM admin_acc_mngmt_notes WHERE JSON_SEARCH(tags, 'all', 'JavaScript') IS NOT NULL
```